# Pass a value from activity to broadcastreceiver and start a service from the broadcast receiver

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have an activity.  It contains a button whose text changes dynamically.  I would like to pass this text to my broadcast receiver which receives the sms.  Now my broadcast receiver should receive the text and based on the text it should start or stop a service.  How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your BroadcastReceiver is defined in a separate class file, then you may simply broadcast the value to that receiver. Once the value is received, do the magic for service by using receiver's `context`

**Update:**

in your activity:

```
Intent in = new Intent("my.action.string");
in.putExtra("state", "activated");
sendBroadcast(in);
```

in your receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  String action = intent.getAction();

  Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);

  if(action.equals("my.action.string")){
     String state = intent.getExtras().getString("state");
     //do your stuff
  }
}
```

in manifest xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".YourBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        <action android:name="my.action.string" />
        <!-- and some more actions if you want -->
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: i have 3 seperate classes for my activity, receiver and service.  i tried to send the value from my activity using                  Intent in = new Intent(); Bundle bun=new Bundle();
bun.putString("state", "activated");in.putExtras(bun);
sendBroadcast(in); - now how to receive this using broadcast receiver.. NOTE : my broadcast receiver is already receiving sms using bundle and performing some operations based on it

Comment: BroadcastReceiver works on the **Action** string defined inside intents. So you need to define it too before broadcasting it, for e.g `in.setAction("my.action.string");` and catch this action string in receiver by using `intent.getAction()`. Make sure your receiver does have `my.action.string` defined in its *intent-filter* section

Comment: That string can be anything? or should I pass some action which is used in the manifest?

Comment: the string can be anything, but it must be defined inside your manifest too under the intent-filter section of your receiver

Comment: but my receiver already contains <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" ></action>.. can a receiver have two actions? I am a beginner in android.  pls explain

Comment: you can have as many actions in your intent-filter as you want. just add your custom action too, like `<action android:name="my.action.string" />`

Comment: I tried. It is showing ANR error - Unable to start receiver: null ptr exception

Comment: i included your code above my code for receiving sms. now it works.  but the code for sms is not working. ok i will handle it.. thanks :)

Comment: I am using the same code, but in my case the string `state` is null. I don't know why. I've rechecked the code multiple times, even the `key` is same.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your activity send an intent to the receiver, and pass the text as an extra

```
Intent i= new Intent(this, YourReceiver.class);
i.putExtra("txt", "the string value");
startActivity(i)
```

And then in your receiver, start the service using the [startService function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: startActivity is used to pass the value to activity.. I would like to pass the value from activity to receiver