# How i pass variable from activity to broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass a value from activity to broadcastreceiver and start a service from the broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390279/pass-a-value-from-activity-to-broadcastreceiver-and-start-a-service-from-the-bro)

I create an application for send incoming call number to bluetooth and i want pass admin number from activity to receiver.How i can do this?

```
  public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();

  registerReceiver(new IncomingCallReceiver(), new  intentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"));

   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            String msg2 = intent.getStringExtra("admin_no");

            if(null == bundle)
                    return;

            Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());

            String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","State: "+ state);

            if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            {
                    String phonenumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```

Comment: Please paste only valid code. You seem to miss the closing brackets and you should try to use ctrl+shift+f to format your code better.

Comment: dupicate, first google your title before submitting an question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390279/pass-a-value-from-activity-to-broadcastreceiver-and-start-a-service-from-the-bro

Answer (score 0):

tried something like this?

```
   Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    intent.putExtra("admin_no","9999999"); // change number here.
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: After mine code on rusume? registerReceiver(new IncomingCallReceiver(), new  intentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"));

Comment: Whenever you want to pass number from anywhere to Receiver, it will call receivers onReceive method if already register with same action